# Closures Cannot access a function

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to understand closures. In the code below, I create an instance of the constructor function `Ninja` and I call the instance `kawazaki`. I expected to be able to access the methods of `Ninja`. However, I am getting a `TypeError: Object #<Ninja> has no method 'feints'` instead.

The output I expected was `1`.

Here is my code:

```
function Ninja() {
    var feints = 0;

    function getFeints() {
        return feints;
    }

    function feints() {
        feints++;
    }
}

var kawazaki = new Ninja();

kawazaki.feints();

console.log(kawazaki.getFeints());
```

Comment: You just created functions inside the constructor. To be able to use them as methods of new instance of `Ninja`, you should save this functions to the `this` object: `this.getFeints = function(){ ... }` and `this.feints = function(){...}`

Comment: *"I expected to be able to access the methods of Ninja."* JavaScript is not as magical as you seem to think it is. `getFeints` and `feints` are just functions local to `Ninja`. They are not accessible from the outside and only exist during the execution of `Ninja`.

Comment: @FelixKling they always made me feel like it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```js
var kawazaki = new Ninja;

kawazaki.feints();

alert(kawazaki.getFeints());

function Ninja() {
    var feints = 0;

    this.getFeints = function () {
        return feints;
    };

    this.feints = function () {
        feints++;
    };
}
```

You need to assing public properties to `this` within the constructor function.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the functions `getFeints` and `feints` is limited to the function Nija. As you can not access to variables declared in a function, you can not access to those functions.

To be able to execute `kawazaki.feints()`, you have to "attach" the function to the Ninja function, as an object (which a function also is)

You will find in these resources several ways to achieve that, and also some deeper explanations:

- [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Answer (score 0):

Closure is a very simple yet largely misunderstood topic.

```
function Ninja() {
    var feints = 0;

    function getFeints() {
        return feints;
    }

    function feintsInc() {
        feints++;
    }

}
```

You have defined the closure alright but please note that a closure is not actually a method of the object. In order to get your desired output you need to call the closures just before closing the object.

```
feintsInc();
getFeints();
```

If,however, you wish to do it as

```
kawazaki.feintsInc();
```

you need to use `this` keywords in your function to get the functions assigned to the object.

```
Note,make sure your functions and variable names don't overlap.
```